# Constant AttributeError on plotly.express

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have been trying to do some visualizations using Jupyter and everytime I use plotly.express always get an AttributeError. I have checked carefully the identation, version and syntax, but I can't see any error. Please, some help:

(I am using matplotlib-2.0.0; pip-20.1.1; plotly-4.8.1)

```
    import plotly.express as px
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    import plotly.figure_factory as ff #aesthetic
    from plotly.subplots import make_subplots #multiplesubplots
    import folium
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    import warnings 
    warnings.filterwarnings ('ignore')
    import plotly as py
    py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

    import os

    try: 
        os.system('rm -rf, Covid-19-Preprocessed-Dataset')  #rm:remove, fr:recursevely all the files

    except:
        print('File does not exist')

    df = pd.read_csv('Covid-19-Preprocessed-Dataset/preprocessed/covid_19_data_cleaned.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
    country_daywise = pd.read_csv('Covid-19-Preprocessed-Dataset/preprocessed/country_daywise.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
    countrywise = pd.read_csv('Covid-19-Preprocessed-Dataset/preprocessed/countrywise.csv')
    daywise = pd.read_csv('Covid-19-Preprocessed-Dataset/preprocessed/daywise.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
    !git clone https://github.com/laxmimerit/Covid-19-Preprocessed-Dataset.git

    #color palette
    cnf = '#393e46'
    dth='#ff2e63'
    rec= '#21bf73'
    act='#fe9'

    fig_a=  px.line(daywise, x='Date', y='Deaths / 100 Cases', color_discrete_sequence=['#DC143C'])
    fig_b=  px.line(daywise, x='Date', y='Recovered / 100 Cases', `enter code here`color_discrete_sequence=['#DC143C'])
    fig_c=  px.line(daywise, x='Date', y='Deaths / 100 Recovered', color_discrete_sequence=['#DC143C'])

    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3, shared_xaxes=False,
                       subplot_titles=('Deaths / 100 Cases', 'Recovered / 100 Cases', 'Deaths / 100 Recovered'))

    fig.add_trace(fig_a['data'][0], row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(fig_b['data'][0], row=1, col=2)
    fig.add_trace(fig_c['data'][0], row=1, col=3)

    fig.update_layout(height = 400)
    fig.show()

____________________________________________________________________________________________________

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-188-aba5b3b9b455> in <module>
    ----> 1 fig_a=  px.line(daywise, x='Date', y='Deaths / 100 Cases', color_discrete_sequence=['#DC143C'])
          2 fig_b=  px.line(daywise, x='Date', y='Recovered / 100 Cases', color_discrete_sequence=['#DC143C'])
          3 fig_c=  px.line(daywise, x='Date', y='Deaths / 100 Recovered', color_discrete_sequence=['#DC143C'])
          4 
          5 fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3, shared_xaxes=False,

    AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'line'
```

Comment: Can you plot the entire code, including the includes?  That can help people try your code, and see what is wrong.

Comment: I just updated the entire code, thanks asylumax for the clarification, I am new here.

Comment: Can you check if the basic plotly line example works?  The syntax looks OK, but if the data isn't right, that could be an issue.   If you print(daywise), you'll see if the data you've read is correct.   I'm not a plotly expert, but I'm also wondering if the "/" is causing an issue.   You could remove the "/" in the data file and the plot function, and see if that works.  Check the data, though.